# How to delete a specific value in ArrayList C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have this code for searching the first value and I don't know how to use index to delete specific line in the ArrayList nabídka. It should be in other method, or how to add index to return?

```
public string vyhledavaniOS()
        {
                foreach (Vozidlo voz in nabídka)
                {
                    if (voz is OsobníVůz)
                        return (voz.TypVozidla() + ": SPZ: " + voz.JakaSPZ + ", Značka: " + voz.JakaZnacka + ", Barva: " + voz.JakaBarva);
                }
        }
```

Comment: Is this you're looking for `arraylist.RemoveAt()`

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to find the position of the value.

Comment: `arralyList.IndexOf`. but I'll suggest you to use `Remove` instead of using `RemoveAt` to make sure you're removing the correct object

Comment: and I strongly recommend you to use `List<T>` over `ArrayList`

Comment: Ok, that works, this is the last project with ArrayList, next time I will use List<T>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

`nabídka.RemoveAt(nabídka.IndexOf(value));`

or

`nabídka.Remove(object);`